# Создание Прайс листа в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

### Ситуация

Требуется реализовать возможность ввода данных в таблицы из админ-панели.

Нужно поделить их на **категории** и **подкатегории**, в каждой можно будет создавать сколько угодно таблиц.

Далее, есть страница со ссылками на категории этих таблиц.

При переходе по ссылке на новую страницу, в выбранной Категории, в цикле, нужно получить не саму разметку, а лишь массив объектов подкатегорий с их таблицами.

Иными словами нужно получить что то на подобие реализации Woocommerce с их категориями и продуктами, однако, в моём случае, нужно выводить не продукты, а данные из таблиц.

Таблица обязательно должна иметь помимо текстовой информации, так же и изображение, каждая таблица должна иметь название(чтобы создать якоря для навигации по прайс листу) и если предоставиться возможность, то желательно и HTML разметка внутри колонки таблицы. Обязательно нужно получить название полей таблицы, ID, и всё что только возможно.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста плагин или что нибудь, что спасёт мою ситуацию.

Я уже пробовал TablePress и другие подобные популярные плагины, но в них нельзя создавать категории и тем более получать объекты данных в коде.

Comment: Узкоспециальная задача, плагин вряд ли найдёте. Наймите разработчика.

Comment: вопрос, в том чтобы посоветовать плагин, ну сами напишите, как раз программирование подтяните